# GONOSUMDB not working since I still get checksum mismatch

Tags: go

I am building a GO microservice and one dependency is from a private repository.
My dockerfile (running go 1.17) contains `GOPROXY` since our dependencies are pulled from a proxy.
I am not sure how to pull the private repository since If I don't use `GOPRIVATE`, I get the following error:

```
#14 44.31 verifying checksum mismatch                                                                      
#14 44.31       downloaded: h1:l3rFJpH48[...]8=                                                                  
#14 44.31       go.sum:     h1:wg1dddxYe[...]U=                                                                  
#14 44.31 
#14 44.31 SECURITY ERROR
#14 44.31 This download does NOT match an earlier download recorded in go.sum.
#14 44.31 The bits may have been replaced on the origin server, or an attacker may
#14 44.31 have intercepted the download attempt.
#14 44.31 
#14 44.31 For more information, see 'go help module-auth'.
```

If I use `GOPRIVATE`, from my understanding the dependencies is not downloaded from the package.

I also tried to add `GONOSUMDB`, but it is basically ignored and I still get the checksum mismatch error.
Any help?

Comment: Just because you are not using the public checksum database, it does not stop go from verifying the packages are valid compared to `go.sum` (as explained in `go help module-auth`). If the version of that module was purposely changed to a different commit (which you should never do), then you will need to manually override the stored `go.sum` values.